# Moving a CAShapeLayer in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

**THE CODE:**

I have a circle created on top of UIImage. The code I have to use to create the Circle:

```
// Show the circle
circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
// Give the layer the same bounds as your image view
[circleLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [colorWheel bounds].size.width,
                                  [colorWheel bounds].size.height)];
// Position the circle anywhere you like, but this will center it
// In the parent layer, which will be your image view's root layer
[circleLayer setPosition:CGPointMake([colorWheel bounds].size.width/2.0f,
                                     [colorWheel bounds].size.height/2.0f)];
// Create a circle path.
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:
                      CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f)];
// Set the path on the layer
[circleLayer setPath:[path CGPath]];
// Set the stroke color
[circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
// Set the stroke line width
[circleLayer setLineWidth:2.0f];

// Add the sublayer to the image view's layer tree
[[colorWheel layer] addSublayer:circleLayer];
```

I have a delegate function to pass the touch points:

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    [pickedColorDelegate getCurrentPosition:(UITouch *)touch];
}
```

And the following code is used for updating the position of the circle:

```
-(void) getCurrentPosition:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [circleLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)];
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

CAShapeLayer does move, but It move's to a wrong position. See the screenshot for instance, I have marked the point where the circle is supposed to be.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The position of the layer has to be expressed in the coordinate space of the `colorWheel`, which is its parent view. You're sending coordinates in the space of `self.view` which I'm guessing is the main view of the view controller.

Your code should be something like:

```
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.colorWheel];
```